# What type of CPU does an Azure Function use?

Tags: azure, azure-functions, serverless

When running an **Azure Function** by using the default *Consumption Plan*, the official docs state:

> Each instance of the Functions host in the Consumption plan is limited to 1.5 GB of memory and one CPU.

However, it doesn't say what type of CPU is used. Is it possible to get any information about e.g. the clock frequency an azure function runs on when using a consumption plan?

Comment: Considering that clouds uses *virtual machines* that are likely configured to create all virtual CPU's to be exactly the same, does it really matter? What problem do you have that you can only solve by knowing the "type" and other facts about the virtual CPU?

Comment: I'm just wondering about the max speed for some complex processing within my function apps.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

CPU information is not published by MS. The only measure you get, is that on a consumption plan you get 100 ACU per instance (per: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-scale#service-limits)

In terms of how much you can get out of a consumption plan, it comes down to testing and seeing how you can split up the work into smaller chunks that sit within the limits of CPU utilization for a single instance, and then scaling that out over multiple instances to get parallel throughput.

Then there's a jump up in cost to a Premium Plan, where you can autoscale but also have control over how much CPU you get per instance