# Finding specific function for high CPU in Azure Function App

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I have an Azure Function App that contains a number of functions. I suspect one of these functions is consuming high CPU, is there a way to view the CPU usage based on the specific function?

Comment: What is the hosting plan you have deployed the functions? Consumption or Dedicated ASP or Premium?

Answer (score 0):

- Azure Portal - Function App Menu - Diagnostic Settings - Check the "Function Application Logs" and "All Metrics" and Send to the Log Analytics workspace (destination) that creates a diagnostic setting and save it.
  [image]

In the Azure Portal - Function App - Diagnose and Solve Problems - Click on the "Availability and Performance" for CPU Analysis on Functions.

- Make Sure you have enabled the [App Insights resource](https://azure.github.io/AppService/2020/04/21/Announcing-Application-Insights-Integration-with-App-Service-Diagnostics.html) associated with that function app is integrated.
- In the "CPU Analysis", you can check the each instance CPU Usage and "CPU drill down" option is for App Level CPU Usage.

Not Sure can we determine the CPU Usage per function because [Scaling Controller](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/event-driven-scaling#runtime-scaling) control the scaling of instances due to/based on high CPU Utilization, I/O requests, High Utilization of Service Bus Queue, Storage Queues of Function App and only few [information](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73062774) provided about CPU Usage in Function App by Microsoft.

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to Azure Portal
2. Choose your Web Apps
3. On the Left pane choose **Diagnose and Solve Problems**

*In this way you can find the high CPU utilization for any app*

[image]

And also choose **Availability and Performance**

[image]

[image]

*you can check **High CPU Analysis** as shown below*

[image]

[image]

*And **Memory Analysis** as shown below*

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately these don't show a breakdown at the function level.

Comment: Yes, I agree. Please check this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-scale#service-limits) for more information.